# MultiPage Hugo Site Deployment with AWS Amplify

Tags: frontend, aws-amplify, hugo, static-site

I am trying to deploy a site using this theme https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/, and to be specific I am testing with this [example site](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/tree/main/exampleSite) on AWS Amplify. I have already tried `Netlify`, and the [`netlify.toml`](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder/blob/main/netlify.toml) has the right build steps. It works great with `Netlify`.

BUT, I want to deploy to AWS Amplify - as I have other dependencies. This is the definition I am using:

```
version: 2
frontend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - hugo
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: []
```

The build logs actually show that the it successfully built the site. Even the site loads fine, but the issue is with the `routes`. Navigating to other sub-routes does NOT work.

I believe this is a problem with

```
Rewrites and redirects
```

And I may have to configure this section separately as this is NOT a single page website. I am reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html) and the guide is not clear for a multi-page site deployment.

Whats the correct way to deploy this on Amplify?

---

**EDIT#1**

```
Trailing slashes and clean URLs

To create clean URL structures like about instead of about.html, static site generators such as Hugo generate directories for pages with an index.html (/about/index.html). Amplify automatically creates clean URLs by adding a trailing slash when required. The table below highlights different scenarios:
```

Amplify indicates it automatically handles this ^, but in my case it seems to not happen. Is there a way to force this on amplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved as follows:

- I was changing the static site from `react` to `Hugo`
- This induced a build step change

BUT ... AWS Amplify did its job correctly. The real issue was with single page settings for react in the `Rewrites and redirects`. Removing those settings helped get the routing issue addressed, as Amplify handles these automatically.